# How to update my database after using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii

I'm using JavaScript/AJAX for the first time so I'm trying to figure out some of the best practices.

Right now, in my view, I display a datatable and then when a call to an outside server returns a value (in this case the accounts balance). I update the datatable.

Now, this is working perfectly, but I'm running into an issue. I would like to *also* update my database with the new "balance" that was found. However, I would like to do this *after* the ajax call has already been made.

Should I do this somewhere in the ajax call in the view? (Which feels wrong) or should I insert this update into the php file that is being called?

Here is the view/ajax call:

```
<script>
function getBalance(){
    $.get("assets/balance.php", "", function(data){

        $('#balance').html(data);
        // alert(data);
    });
}
getBalance();
</script>
```

and here is the *balance.php*:

```
<?php 
include "../protected/components/helpers.php";
    /**
    *@method CheckBalance() : this  method helps to get the balance info of the tigo cash subscriber using tigo rwanda middleware
    *@param string  $msisdn : this is the mobile number of the tigo cash subscriber
    *@param string $pin    : this is the pin number of the tigo cash account 
    *@return returns the decoded answer either as the balance (int) or a warning (string)
    */
    function BalanceCall($msisdn,$pin){

        //Store your XML Request in a variable
        $input_xml = '<soapenv:Envelope>...';

        // returns a long xml string reply
        $xmlstring = curl_exec($soap_do);

        // this returns either the balance (int) or an error (string)
        return $result = Helpers::decodeBalanceString($xmlstring);
    }

    echo $result = BalanceCall($msisdn, $pin);
?>
```

I know that the `$.get` function is used like this:

```
$.get(URL,data,function(data,status,xhr),dataType)
```

should I be doing this action where I pass in data?

Comment: what is the issue while running your code?

Comment: i would do it in the ajax call. Maybe you want to send content-lenght header, flush the output and then make the "longer" operation.

Comment: So, there isn't an issue - but I'm trying to figure out if I should update my database in the view (Where  I do the ajax call) or if I should do it in balance.php - which is the function called.

Comment: It seems however, that if someone then disables javascript then I am not able to update my database at all. Should I do this update in the controller then?

Comment: Since you are looking for best practices, I would suggest the following: You should update your database first and then get the value from your database to show in your view. That way you don't run the risk of showing a value that could disappear from you view since it is not stored. Further, you might consider not using ajax for this but loading the data server side and then only fetching it for your view from your database.